# Swift JSON cannot get second variable

Tags: ios, json, laravel-4, swift

I built a backend API to my app in Laravel (PHP). The return from the method I am calling (create user) is:

```
{"success":true,"userid":"23"}
```

but when accessing `userid` in Swift it returns a null? It can access the `success` variable.

Here is the code for my request:

```
// create the user
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost/laravel/myapi/public/createUser"))
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var params = ["username":txtUsername.text, "email":txtEmail.text, "password":txtPassword.text] as Dictionary
        var err: NSError?
        request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            //            println("Response: \(response)")
            var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        println("Body: \(strData)")
            var err: NSError?
            let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments & .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSDictionary

            if(err) {
                println(err!.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                var success = json["success"] as? Int
                if(success == 1) {
                    var id = json["userid"] as? Int
                    self.lblTaken.text = "\(id)"
                }
            }
            })

        task.resume()
```

the `println("Body: \(strData)")` prints out:

```
Body: {"success":true,"userid":"23"}
```

But when trying to access the `userid` variable, it returns `nil`

Am I doing something wrong when trying to access the userid?

**UPDATE**

if I print out:

`println(json.valueForKey("userid"))`

it prints out the userid, but if I assign it to the variable, the variable returns a `null` still

Comment: What does `println("JSON:\(json)") show?

Comment: @Paulw11 it prints out: `JSON:{
    success = 1;
    userid = 23;
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The userId comes as a string. So, the problem is, you try to cast a string to an integer using as? and fail.

From Apple docs:

The as? operator performs a conditional cast of the expression to the specified type. The as? operator returns an optional of the specified type. At runtime, if the cast succeeds, the value of expression is wrapped in an optional and returned; otherwise, the value returned is nil. If casting to the specified type is guaranteed to fail, a compile-time error is raised. For example, casting to a type that’s neither a subclass or superclass of the type of the expression is an error.

Comment: yes of course, you can cast a bool to an int but not a string to an int.

Comment: Ah I see, if I return the `id` as `AnyObject`, then it returns the `userid`. Is there a way to cast it from `AnyObject` to an `int` ?

Comment: It's not an `AnyObject` that can be cast to an `Int` - it _is_ a `String`. Use `.integerValue`.